# How 0061 736d represents \0asm?

Tags: c++, webassembly

I just started to learn web assembly . I found this text

> "In binary format The first four bytes represent the Wasm binary magic
> number \0asm; the next four bytes represent the Wasm binary version in
> a 32-bit format"

I am not able to understand this . Can anyone explain me this

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`\0` is a character with code 0 (the first `00` in `00617369`), the remaining three are literal characters `a`, `s` and `m`. With [codes](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/ASCII#Printable_characters) 97, 115 and 109 respectively, or `61`, `73` and `6d` in hex.